# Prove the inequality $b\le \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$

Tags: inequality

How do i prove $b\le \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ ?
What i think is :

$\begin{align}
a^2& \gt 0,\, b^2 \gt 0 \\
b &= \sqrt{b^2}\\
&\le\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \\
\therefore b &\le \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}
\end{align}$

Am i right? Please do a correction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not true that $b =\sqrt {b^{2}}$. You have to say $b \leq |b| =\sqrt {b^{2}} \leq \sqrt {a^{2}+b^{2}}$.